# How to Specify custom filter in application.yml Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, api-gateway

I have a custom gateway filter MYGatewayFilter.java file now i want to use this gateway filter with my route written in application.yml

```
 spring:
  cloud:
   gateway:
    routes:
      - id: login2_route
      uri: http://127.0.0.1:8083/login
      predicates:
       - Path: /login/
      filters:
```

How do i define filters for above route

Custom Filter MyGatewayFilter.java

```
public class MyGatewayFilter implements GatewayFilter {
    @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
      ServerHttpRequest request;
      if(request.getHeaders().get("x-mydata")!=null){
         request= exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("my-new-header",request.getHeaders().get("x-mydata").get(0)).build();
      }

      return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem is the filter not getting read or what.Also paste the filter code.

Comment: @GrinishNepal filter code is attached, problem is that how to specify this filter in application.yml filters properties

Comment: Why is this -1?  I am trying to figure out the same thing, there is no documentation on how to add a custom filter to a route.

Comment: did you solve the problem, I am facing the same problem but I still did not success after tried the solution.@GOURAV MEHTA

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of implementing GatewayFilter you should implement GatewayFilterFactory

and make it a Component:

```
@Component
public class MyGatewayFilter implements GatewayFilterFactory {
```

Then you can refer to it by the bean name in your route.

```
filters:
- MyGatewayFilter
```

The documentation on this isn't very good at the moment.  I was only able to figure this out by looking at the source code for spring-cloud-gateway on github

Comment: Pay attention that the `PropertiesRouteDefinitionLocator` removes the final part of the filter name if it is equal to `RoutePredicateFactory` or `GatewayFilterFactory`.  
  
See: `PropertiesRouteDefinitionLocator`, `FilterDefinition`, `NameUtils`.  
  
So if your filter is in class `PrincipalNameGatewayFilterFactory` you have to configure the route with filter name `PrincipalName`.

Comment: Hi, did you have a miminal demo about this custom gateway filter. @devo

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement `GatewayFilterFactory`

```
@Component
public class DemoGatewayFilter implements GatewayFilterFactory<DemoGatewayFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            System.out.println("gateway filter name "+config.getName());
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Config newConfig() {
        return new Config("DemoGatewayFilter");
    }

    public static class Config {

        public Config(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        private String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

and in application.yml file

```
 spring:
  application:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: MayApplication
        uri: http://myapplication:8080
        predicates:
        - Path=/apipath/to/filter/**
        filters:
          - DemoGatewayFilter
```

Comment: I tried your way, but id did not enter the filter when do a request to spring gateway. this is my code to reproduce, I did not know where am I going wrong: https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/java-learn  @Nitin

Answer (score 2):

I think there are some changes in Spring Cloud Gateway 2.2.1.
I referred to [SaveSessionGatewayFilterFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/7e4f44a46e6251f71d9e04b1ab5c205d3f4327c3/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/SaveSessionGatewayFilterFactory.java).

```java
@Component
public class DemoGatewayFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
/*
it works too
       return new GatewayFilter() {
           @Override
           public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
               return chain.filter(exchange);
           }
       }
*/
    }

}
```

and in application.yml file

```yaml
 spring:
  application:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: MayApplication
        uri: http://myapplication:8080
        predicates:
        - Path=/api/path/to/filter/**
        filters:
          - DemoGatewayFilter
```

Comment: Hi, I follow your advice and make a minimal reproduce demo:https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/java-learn. after startup the project, I do a request to http://localhost:8081/music/1, the request did not trigger the filter DemoGatewayFilter. @Yubi Lee

Comment: AbstractGatewayFilterFactory should be extends, not implements. GatewayFilterFactory, however, is an interface and can be implemented.